# Not able to expand or see jobs under SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server

When I am trying to expand jobs under SQL Server Agent it shows error:

> **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
>   should be discarded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4035&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476

Comment: Repair your SQL Server. It should solve the problem. Links provided are vague

Comment: How can I repair SQL Server ?????

Comment: This problem occurs when your database is offline or you do not have access to the particular database. You can try by restating your SQL Server or by taking access of the database. Please refer [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/956179/error-message-when-you-click-the-databases-node-in-sql-server-management-studio-in-sql-server-2008-failed-to-retrieve-data-for-this-request) link

Comment: thanks @Prafulla my answer was off track. :)